# How to create a secure login page using VS 2010/ASP.Net/VB.Net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security, encryption, authentication

I would like to create a secure login page for a pre-defined set of users (so no creating username/passwords by the users themselves). I've looked up a few sites and they all seem to suggest using Microsoft's Membership or something. I am not very sure as to why that's used, but all you need to know is that I will be creating the login details. I just need to make the login secure, ie, no duplicate logins, no logins from different browsers and cookies and sessions and encryption and all that. Any one have the code/links to where I can get all this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that you are moving on the wrong direction. Why the no dublicate login, is making secure ? Why the different browser making secure ? its very easy to send false data about the browser. Microsoft login is very good and secure, see any tutorial and just use it. The rest you say have not making secure at all.

Comment: @Aristos: By duplicate login, I mean that the same user should not be able to login again in either the same or a different browser. It's a requirement. Where can I find articles about Microsoft login? Please note that I will be creating the login credentials and so will not need membership or anything of that sort.

Comment: To avoid the doublicate login, you just check if the user is all ready loged in. I think that you can find a lot of tutorials for the ms login, on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options here.

Case 1 : 
Role your own security but bear in mind you will oversee something. Security isn't easy and its sooo easy to overlook something. Hashing , salting , encryption etc...

Case 2:
If its a simple site just use Microsoft memberschipprovider. It is good and they spend 3 years tweaking / patching it. You can also override the memberschipServiceprovider to implement some additional security. or to tell the memberschipprovider what data should be used.

Optional:
Extend your ISS server with this open-source firewall : http://www.aqtronix.com/?PageID=99
It provides some cool features for "free"(If you have access to install it).

The best security is when you find the balance between secure and accessible vs Top-security and inaccessible.

And to answer the link part of your question: 
http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page

If you want more information on microsofts' memberschipprovider :
Google :) or Bing or yahooooo!

Goodluck